# Python: Choropleth map not showing color

Tags: python, jupyter, choropleth

I'm working on a covid project in jupyter notebooks and cannot seem to get the choropleth map to update by date. I am using plotly.express and do not have much experience using it. I have researched multiple similar issues but nothing has worked for me and I have seen multiple similar examples except they end up working. Been bugging me for the past couple hours. Any advice would be much appreciated!

"case" column is cumulative.

Plot and code below:

[image: Code & Plot image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, 'locations' must be specified with the shortened state name.

```
import plotly.express as px

# ex: state=['CA','TX','NY','NY','CA']
fig = px.choropleth(df,
                  locations=state,
                  color='cases',
                  hover_name='state',
                  locationmode='USA-states',
                  animation_frame='date')

fig.update_layout(
title_text = 'State Rankings',
title_x=0.5,
geo_scope='usa',
geo=dict(showframe=False,
        showcoastlines = False))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Such a simple solution to a frustrating problem.